# C# MVC3 Model Invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I am currently getting a error in the model saying it cannot convert from String to a Model.
This happens once I try and add a new database table entry. I am using SQL Server and for the front end I am using c# mvc3 razor view.

Model:

```
    namespace NBProfiler.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class PersonContempancy
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> AttainedDate { get; set; }
        public int FrameworkId { get; set; }
        public int ContempancyCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int ContempancyId { get; set; }
        public int ContempancyLevelId { get; set; }
        public int FrameworkLevelId { get; set; }

        public virtual Contempancy Contempancy { get; set; }
        public virtual ContempancyCategory ContempancyCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual FrameworkLevel FrameworkLevel { get; set; }
        public virtual Framework Framework { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public virtual ContempancyLevel ContempancyLevel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

       ViewBag.Contepancies = db.Contempancies.ToList();
       ViewBag.ContempancyCategory = db.ContempancyCategories.ToList();
       ViewBag.ContempancyLevel = db.ContempancyLevels.ToList();
       ViewBag.FrameworkLevel = db.FrameworkLevels.ToList() ;
       ViewBag.Person = db.People.ToList();
       ViewBag.Framework = db.Frameworks.ToList();

        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Mapping/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PersonContempancy personcontempancy)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.PersonContempancies.Add(personcontempancy);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }



        ViewBag.Contepancies = db.Contempancies.ToList();
        ViewBag.ContempancyCategory = db.ContempancyCategories.ToList();
        ViewBag.ContempancyLevel = db.ContempancyLevels.ToList();
        ViewBag.FrameworkLevel = db.FrameworkLevels.ToList();
        ViewBag.Person = db.People.ToList();
        ViewBag.Framework = db.Frameworks.ToList();

        return View(personcontempancy);
    }
```

And finally View: (I have removed the other items from the view as they are all the same code so to shorten it on here I deleted it)

```
    @model NBProfiler.Model.PersonContempancy


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Map Skill to Person</h2>


<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href="../../Content/themes/start/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>PersonContempancy</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
           Name:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Person, new SelectList(ViewBag.Person as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "PersonId", "PersonName"), "Choose Name")

        </div>

        @*<div class="editor-field">*@
        <div class="editor-label">
                @*@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContempancyCategory)*@
            </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContempancyCategory, new   SelectList(ViewBag.ContempancyCategory as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "ContempancyCategoryId", "ContempancyCategoryName"),"Select", new {id = "category" })

        <p>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Map Skill" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Show Table", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#category").change(function () {
      var idCat = $(this).val();
      $.getJSON("/Mapping/contempancies", { CategoryID: idCat },
      function (MyData) {
      var select = $("#contempancy");
      select.empty();
      $.each(MyData,function(index, itemData) {
      select.append($('<option/>', {
      value: itemData.Value,
      text: itemData.Text
      }));
      });
      });
      });
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Quite a lot of code there. Perhaps it would be beneficial to identify the methods and line numbers that are causing the problem? I can't really tell and there's too much code to look through without an idea of the cause. Additionally and as a side - "contempancy" looks like a typo - assume it should be "competency"

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: Im new to MVC and C# so Im not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: @Maarten the exception happens in the Modelstate.isvalid in the controller post "create" method. I added breakpoint there and the model is empty so I used the stack trace and found errors in the model saying it trying to convert string to a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is your treating your *view* model as an *entity* model which is never a good idea.

When passing data to/from a view you should have an explicit view model and only pass the data that your view needs. Also, you are coupling your data layer with your view which defeats the purpose of MVC!

In your example, if `PersonContempancy` is indeed a view model (and not an entity) then you should use it to create a new entity mapping the data it needs, [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is a pretty nifty library for that sort of thing.

```
public class PersonContempancyViewModel
{
    // update with properties the view needs
}

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Create(PersonContempancyViewModel viewModel) 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        var entity = new PersonContempancyEntity();
        // map properties from view model to entity
        // entity.FrameworkId = viewModel.FrameworkId etc..
        db.PersonContempancies.Add(entity);  
        db.SaveChanges(); 

        return RedirectToAction("Index");   
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: well PersonContempancy is a model that was auto generated by ADO.NET frpm a database table. So your saying add the same properties into a new view model?

Comment: @user1586899 Yes, you shouldn't pass entities (generated models) into your view, you should have specific view models (to decouple your data layer from your view). My biggest concern is your trying to return an entity from your view.

Comment: thank you! works fine now. :) I know ViewBags are bad idea but with deadline I cant change it so will leave it.

Comment: @user1586899 There is nothing wrong with using `ViewBag` to pass data to your view (that's it's purpose). Might be better placed in your view model though, however, the preference is yours :)